# Loop conditions in multiple lines using algorithmic package

Tags: line-breaking, indentation, algorithms

I am working on a paper in double-column format, and I am using the `algorithmic` package to typeset my algorithms. One of my while loops' condition is a bit long hence doesn't fit into the column.

When I try to split the condition into several lines, it is not properly indented, as in `\WHILE{this is the first line which barely fits into the column \\ this is the second line`}.

I have also tried the following:

```
\WHILE{this is the first line which barely fits into the column \\
  \hskip\algorithmicindent this is the second line}
```

However, it indents the second line of the condition only as much as the body of the `WHILE`, it needs to be aligned with the first line of the loop condition. How can I achieve this?

MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \WHILE{There is an element which satisfies \\
         \hskip\algorithmicindent properties which are long}
    \STATE{while-body}
  \ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you be able to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem? This includes specifying whether you are using the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) or [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following MWE provides `\pushcode[<num>]` which indents your code `<num>` indents (`\algorithmicindent`) from the left margin. The default (since `<num>` is optional) is `1` indent. You could also "undent" your code by specifying a negative number (be careful that this might push code into the line numbers).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmic
\newcommand{\pushcode}[1][1]{\hskip\dimexpr#1\algorithmicindent\relax}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \WHILE{this is the first line which barely fits into the column \\
    \pushcode[2] this is the second line}
    \STATE here is some content
  \ENDWHILE
  \STATE here is some more content
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}​
```